# optimize 'for loop' with lambda in python

Tags: python

I am using regex for finding the pattern in two different columns(`Description and Labels`) from two different dataframe(`Input data` and `Mapping data`) and if the pattern matches then map the `Labels` from `Mapping data` with `Input Data`.

```
def func2(x,pattern,labels):
    """
    # Searching pattern in Input Data and returning the matched Description
    #
    #Input Parameter
    # 1) x             : Description column of Input Data 
    # 2) pattern       : Pattern column of Mapping Data
    # 3) Labels        : Labels column of Mapping Data
    """
    for p,d in zip(pattern, labels):
        if re.search(r'\b'+ p +r'\b',x):
            return d
    for p,d in zip(pattern, labels):
        if re.search(p,x):
            return d
```

This code is working perfectly fine, but as my data is hug, its taking much time.Is there any otherway to replace this `for loop` with `Lambda` function

Comment: Lambda functions won't be any faster.

Comment: Why not combine the 2 for loop bodies as a start?

Comment: you'd better change your regex expression